# How to handle one side bar on many different sides (how to handle the update of this sidebar)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site (witch many pages) and a side bar. But I want to have this bar for every page (go there by links) and also a settings button for the same for each page. Is there a way to do it better than copy it everytime I update the side menu or the settings to every page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the sidebar in your site's main Javascript file. This way when you need to add an update, you can just update your Javascript and it will change on all pages. However, if you have a side bar that needs to be updated regularly with updates from throughout your site (ie a side bar with links to blogs), you'll have to use a server-side language.